# Visual Studio 2017 hangs while debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2017

I tried looking this up on the visual studio support site and apparently this should have been fixed. I am still experiencing periodic hanging while debugging.

I am running the most recent update of visual studio 2017: 15.2

I have tried disabling extensions (Resharper 2017 Ultimate, Developer Analytics, etc.) without any luck. Its very frustrating, because I end up having to end the Visual Studio task in task manager.

Has anyone else had similar issues with 15.2?

**UPDATE**

I [found this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/55303/visual-studio-may-terminate-unexpectedly-when-runn.html) on the MS site. I had looked up and down, but once I added a 15.2 search criteria it showed up.

Comment: strange, I have this issue with 15.3.1

Comment: @FatShogun, I have not experienced it in 15.3.1, yet. I'll keep an eye on it though.

Comment: I have this issue with v15.3.5. After starting the debug session, VS hangs and the process needs to be killed.

Answer (score 1):

I had issue with Visual Studio 2019 hangs while debugging. I have deleted .vs(hidden) folder. It works fine then.

The .vs directory can be found on the same directory where the solution file located. (It was hidden by default, we need to enable the visibility on file explorer setting at windows )

Comment: where is it located ?

Answer (score 0):

Updating to 15.2(26430.16) has solved this issue. I preformed the update almost 2 weeks ago and have not had an issue since.